# Extending a built-in function in Python proper syntax?

Tags: python, built-in

```
class EvenOnly(list):
    def append(self, integer):
        if not isinstance(integer, int):
            raise TypeError(f"'{integer}' is not an integer.")
        if integer % 2:
            raise ValueError(f"'{integer}' is not an even integer")
        super().append(integer)
```

Notice the "super()" call at the end of the code. If I change it to "list.append(integer)" which, from my understanding, just specifies the parent class it is calling to (similar to multi inheritance), it provides this error when executing:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

Why is that?
I understand that it's unnecessary to specify the parent class in this case, but I wonder what's making the difference that causes an error.

Comment: Invoking a method on an explicit parent class would be written `list.append(self, integer).  The magic that allows `super()` to work with no parameters doesn't apply in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of

```
super().append(integer)
```

in your particular context would be

```
list.append(self, integer)
```

Since `list` is a type, you need to explicitly specify the list as well. `list.append` is a function object, whereas `self.append` is a *bound method object*. One takes two arguments and the other takes one.